# ServiceHandle is 0

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

I'm trying to write simple wcf service self hosted in windows service
But ServiceHandle of windows service is always 0

I need to detect hardware change using RegisterDeviceNotification
One of it's parameters is Handle, in my case is ServiceHandle

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase, IMyService
{
    private ServiceHost host;

public static void Main()
{
    ServiceBase.Run(new MyService());
}

public MyService()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), new Uri(@"net.pipe://localhost/MyService"));
        host.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MyService:", e.Message);
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    host.Close();
}

#region IMyService Members

public void Register()
{
    //Here the ServiceHost is 0        
}
#endregion
```

}

What can cause the problem?
Thanks

Comment: What do you need the ServiceHandle for?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553

Comment: Uaaahh! The service class should not implement the operation contract!! Keep this separate and have a new class implement the service contract.

Answer (score 1):

The `ServiceHandle` - no matter what value - is not required to host a WCF service as a Windows service. Simply instantiate the `ServiceHost` in `OnStart` and close it in `OnStop` and you should be fine.

This is why `ServiceHandle` is always 0 in your case:

Your Windows service class implements your WCF service contract. This is not a good thing and is also the cause for the `ServiceHandle` property being 0. For every call to the WCF service a new instance of the `MyService` class is instantiated (if you didn't change the defaults). This instance is a *normal instance* of the class that doesn't *know* it's a Windows Service, so all Windows Service related properties have their default values. Only the instance that's created by the Windows Service manager has all the appropriate properties set.

You can try for yourself: In `OnStart`, insert the following line and inspect the value for `myServiceVar.ServiceHandle`. You'll see it is `0`:

```
MyService myServiceVar = new MyService();
```

What you *really*  want to do is the following: Have a different class implement the service contract, for example like that:

```
public class MyWCFService : IMyService
{
    public static IntPtr ServiceHandle;

    public void Register()
    {
        // Use MyWCFService.ServiceHandle here
    }  
}
```

In the `OnStart` method, set the `ServiceHandle` variable of `MyWCFService`:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        MyWCFService.ServiceHandle = this.ServiceHandle;

        host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyWCFService), new Uri(@"net.pipe://localhost/MyService"));
        host.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("MyWCFService:", e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to self host wcf service in windows service
Like here [link](http://keyvan.io/selfhosting-wcf-services-in-windows-services#comments)

Comment: I know. This doesn't answer the question what you need the service handle for. Have you ever created an installed a Windows Service?

Comment: I need to detect hardware change using RegisterDeviceNotification One of it's parameters is Handle, in my case is ServiceHandle
For your question, yes!

Comment: Well, that's an entirely different matter - originally, your question sounded like "I'm trying to host a WCF service within a Windows Service but I can't because the ServiceHandle is 0". Now you're saying: My question doesn't have any connection to WCF whatsoever. I'm trying to create a Windows Service and the ServiceHandle is always 0.

Comment: Edited my answer to show why `ServiceHandle` is 0 and how to do it right.